# Where to store previous values in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that represents a list of pages (used when paging through search results). For example, When I click on page 3, and then click a search result, a new page appears, and the component is destroyed. When I go back, it recreates the component, and the selected page is reset to 1. I want to keep the last selected page value, and default the selected page to that when the component is recreated. Where can I store a 'previouslySelectedPage' value, and how can I access it? (I'm a noob at React, do I have to store it in the state/props of a parent element that does not get destroyed when I click a search result, so that old values can be retained?)

Comment: "do I have to store it in the state/props of a parent element that does not get destroyed when I click a search result, so that old values can be retained?"

Basically yes.. or localStorage... or some other persistent store like redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to store in the state of a parent that doesn't get unmounted and re-mounted. And then you can pass those state values as props to the child component.

The other option is to use something like redux to create data stores in your application.  Adding redux to your app will not be a trivial undertaking but may provide some good value long term if your app is complex and will need to scale.

Comment: actually the project is using redux already, but having just been introduced to these technologies, I don't really know how to use them. I'm guessing I need to add a previousPage variable to the store somehow?

Comment: Great, you'll need to have an action creator that'll define the "changePage" action (or whatever you to call it), the component that has the page changing controls will need to fire that action (it should get the action as a prop from mapDispatchToProps()) and you'll need a reducer that captures that action.  Then you'll need a container to map the reducer state to props in any component that needs to be aware of the current page number.  That's a lot of stuff for someone new to redux, so If you can provide me a fiddle, codepen or a github project, I'll be happy to write some example code.